# Problem 2 Exercise 4.3 krieszig function analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I am self studying Functional analysis from Krieszig and could not solve this problem

Question is:

> If $p$ is a real-valued functional as defined in Hahn-Banach theorem i.e., $p$ is subadditive,
>
> and $p( ax) = |a|\;p(x)$ , $a$ is scalar,
>
> then prove that $|p(x) - p(y)|$ $\leqq $ $p(x-y)$ .

Please help

Comment: This is not true. Or is $p\ge 0$ always and $p(ax) = |a|p(x)$?

Comment: @amsmath  really sorry it was a typing mistake. I have edited it. Can you please help .

Comment: I have written an answer which should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $p\ge 0$ and $p(ax) = |a|p(x)$. Then
$$
p(x)-p(y) = p(x-y+y)-p(y)\le p(x-y)+p(y)-p(y) = p(x-y).
$$
Similarly,
$$
p(y)-p(x)\le p(y-x) = p((-1)(x-y)) = p(x-y).
$$

Comment: p greater than or equal to 0 is not necessary, I think!

Comment: It is necessary, but it follows from subadditivity and $p(ax) = |a|p(x)$.